# make iframe content clickable

Tags: jquery, iframe

hey  guys am have the following below fiddle

[JSfidle link](http://jsfiddle.net/ejNf2/)

problem am facing is that am not able to click the iframe content as the image is coming on top of it.
Earlier i tried rotating the image but then the peel effect doesnt come. 
Can you let me know how can make the iframe clickable

```
     $(function(){
    var show=false;
    var expand=function(){
   $('#page_peel_img').stop().animate({
        width: 500, 
        height: 500
    },{
        duration:500,
        queue:false,
        complete:function(){
            show=true;
        }
    });


    $('#page_peel').stop().animate({
        width: 500, 
        height: 500
    },{
        duration:500
    });
 };

      var close=function(){
          $('#page_peel_img').stop().animate({
            width: 50,
            height: 50
        }, 
        { duration: "medium", 
          queue:false,
          complete:function(){
            show=false;
          }
        });

        $('#page_peel').stop().animate({
            width: 50,
            height: 50
        }, 400);
```

};

```
       //$('#page_peel').hover(expand,close);

   $('#page_peel_img').click(function() {
    //alert(1);

    if(!show){
        expand();
        show=true;
    }else{
        close();
        show=false;
    }

});

});
```

Comment: Will it be fine, if the `img` size is small while its in open mode.

Comment: @Anup :No image should be same otherwise how will i get the peel effect

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use transform/-webkit-transform(chrome browser) trick.

See my finddle   http://www.jsfiddle.net/ejNf2/2/

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);-transform: rotate(-45deg);
```

In my example the top menu (abous us, customer centre) can be clickable. You must change the image and rotate it.

Let me know if I can be of any more help.

Comment: without rotation is it possible since i want to keep the page peel effect ?

Comment: Is this what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/ejNf2/4/   ? (checked in chrome and firefox)

Comment: i want something like this  http://noop-demo-pagepeel.blogspot.com.au/

but the content is an iframe and it should be clickable thats it.

Comment: Did you tried my previous example (http://jsfiddle.net/ejNf2/4/) ? What is wrong with my approach ?
I saw your model page. Here (http://jsfiddle.net/JuS8y/1/) is your model peel efect
It's pretty simple. 
But I have one question. When you click in iframe do you want the page to be opened in the same iframe or in the whole page (like in your example)?

Comment: see how i have done it.
here
http://jsfiddle.net/2vf8s/

also please check this 
http://jsfiddle.net/xQR92/
the iframe content is moving kind off when am animating the main div.let me know y its happening and how i can correct it